# Probability- Median absolute deviation

Tags: probability

Let $m(x)$ denote the median of $X$ and let the median absolute deviation of $X$ be defined as $\vert X - m(x) \vert$

Given $P[X=0]= \frac{1}{4}$ and $P[X=2]=\frac{1}{8}$ and $P[X=5]=\frac{1}{4}$ and $P[X=6]= \frac{1}{6}$ finde the median absolute deviation.

Since the median is defined as:

Let $F(m)$ denote the cumulative density function then the median is the value m such that $F(m) \geq \frac{1}{2}$

so I began by adding the probabilities:

$\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{5}{8}$

so $m(x)=5$

now if I plug in all the values subtract them from the median with a summation this is of course way off from my answer choices..However we know that the deviation is the square root of the variance can this be used. Did I even find m(x) correctly if so my problem is what is X in the situation?

Comment: You mean that the median absolute deviation is defined as the *median* of |X-m(x)| and that it the median is defined as the *smallest* value of $m$ such that $F(m)\ge 1/2$

Comment: so I take the median of all of the values minus median?

Comment: Yes. However,  the probabilities don't add up to one so you can't do this until that's corrected.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is a random variable so $|X-m(X)|$ is a random variable could equal $5,3,0,$ or $1$ depending whether $X = 0,2,5$ or $6.$ The median absolute deviation is the *median* of this random variable, so you want to take its median, just like you took the median of $X$ to get $m(X).$

Comment: I will need a little more a hint than this as I am confused as to how to find the median of x - m(x)

Comment: @user418682 I'm a little confused about this myself since the probabilities don't add up to one.

Comment: yes this question does fail the basic axioms but the question is from the inifinite actuary

Comment: The answer sheet says the answer is (P[x-5]<t)<1/2 is when t=1. Why is there a t?

Comment: I will redit this and put there answer and ask for the reasoning behind it